# java regex pattern matcher to identify unusual characters and asian ideographs

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to go through the following text to extract some certain elements based on the java regex patterns:

```
『卥』
```

For this element `『卥』`, I guess I'll always be able to find the item between `『` and `』` and extract it, this should be feasable because those are pretty unusual entities so it should be a good basis to identify and extract whatever comes between them, i.e. `卥`

There's a lot of information on using java regex pattern matcher to match entire classes of characters but I've not found much on matching just one or two specific ones and removing things from between. That's certainly possible I would think, isn't it? How to do that?

Ideally something like

```
match(`『` and `』`)
{
     print(what comes between them)
}
```

Tried this, but didn't work:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class text_processing
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String sCurrentLine; 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/matthias/Workbench/SUTD/1_February/brute_force/items.csv"));


        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/『(.*?)』/");


        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(sCurrentLine);
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your consideration

Comment: post a complex example along with expected output.

Comment: maybe like that pseudocode?

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō the pseudocode helped me frame an answer. Let me know if u were looking for that

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō edited my answer , just use the " " not the /

Comment: Don't print a Matcher - it's rather pointless.

Comment: ultimately, i'll be putting it to a table, it's just that I'm kind of debugging it right now so I'd like to look at the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text = ...; // your text
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "『([^』]*)』" );
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( text );
if( mat.find() ){
    System.out.println( mat.group(1) );
}
```

You can use this repeatedly to find *all* occurrences:

```
while( mat.find() ){
    System.out.println( mat.group(1) );
}
```

Comment: with mat.group(1) is returns an index out of bounds exception: no group 1, seems it also returns those funny characters `『` and `』`, is there a way to exclude them?

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō This works perfectly fine. The parenthese delimit what group(1) should return; this excludes the "funny chars".

Answer (score 2):

The below will be ur regex

```
"『(.*?)』"
```

Check out the working example here: https://regex101.com/r/lO8xR1/1